# How can I get data in callback mongodb and Put in a variable? , javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, callback

```
   await mongodb.connect(process.env.MongoUrl , async (err, c)=>
   {
    if(err){console.log(err)}
    var GetData = c.db("Data").collection("Servers")
    const Server = await GetData.findOne({IdServer:id}).then(r => {return r})
    if(Server != null)
    {
    return callback(Server.prefix)
    }
    else
    {
    GetData.insertOne({IdServer:id,Sersial:false,JoinServerHistory:new Date().toLocaleDateString(),History:"-",prefix:"-",caunt:50})
    return callback("")
    }
  })
}
```

const Prfix =  GetPrfix("9273490839208409" , (r) => {console.log(r)})

///////  ^<<<<<<<< take "r" and and Put in a variable    <<<<<<<< ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to declare it first, then assign it the value:

```js
var newVar = null;
await mongodb.connect(process.env.MongoUrl , async (err, c)=>
   {
    if(err){console.log(err)}
    var GetData = c.db("Data").collection("Servers")
    const Server = await GetData.findOne({IdServer:id}).then(r => {newVar = r;}) // Right here is the magic
    // ... SOME MORE CODE
  })
}
// You can use `newVar` here as `r`.
```

Comment: thank you for help me but its work inside MongoDB if i do console.log outside MongoDB well be value null,

Comment: That's because JavaScript is asynchronous, so before `newVar` is assigned, it moves on the the next part. You can use async/await, promises, or use deasync.